# How do I post comment in dark background

Tags: editor

Call me crazy...
Hey i wanna know that how you people comment or ask your question in dark background. I am new at this site so tried searching the FAQs but couldn't find the answer. How do you write your code related thing in different background and general sentences in simple background?

```
 **Its a Check and it works.**
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - there's a help button in the editor.

Comment: hmm...that is of quite help. Thanks @krystanhonour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

> like this because this is a blockquote and you can use either a > prefix or highlight and click the speech marks

the other is `a bit like this` and that is a back tick ` which denotes a code block or you can highlight code like this

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int foo() 
        {
            return 1+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Which does a similar thing and you do that by highlighting a block and clicking the `{}` button or you can indent from the beginning by 4 which buts it into that mode.

There are formatting hints in the editor (the orange question mark)